# How do i make 2 divs in eachother

Tags: html, css

How do i make a div like this?
https://i.gyazo.com/cc34cdba5d8ef4969212c45935caf165.png
Its 1 div, the image (car) and the background thats black with text on it. And when you hover, the red fade goes away.
This is a complete gyazo of what I´m trying to do.
https://i.gyazo.com/51d360e8f4a6408dbed789f0d702dbc7.png

Here´s the picture of the car: **You need atleast 10 rep to post more than 3 links, the link should be in the comments!**

**What i tried:**

Making 1 div named black, taking it like this:

```
<div class="black">
<img src="urltocar" height="x" width="x">
</div>
```

Styled the black div to get bigger than the car itself so it got a black background, but it never worked.

Comment: https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/75e8bb7e5d1473412157.png

Comment: Been out 10 sec, -1, why?

Comment: Your images are a little confusing. You also didn't post any CSS code, only the HTML. HTML is about structure while CSS is about design.

Comment: -1 because this question seems to lack research effort :/ I would suggest that you first read through / watch some tutorials on HTML and CSS. [(Intro to HTML)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/s2moc0gt/1/

Basically just some CSS:

```
.img-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("https://rocket-league.com/content/media/items/avatar/220px/75e8bb7e5d1473412157.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.red-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, red);
}

.red-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll want to make sure the the linear-gradient has all the browser prefixes (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp), and you'll probably want a transition on the opacity so that it's not as jarring. But this should start you off.